# Newest product filter in React doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, e-commerce

I have 3 filters: ascending, descending (price) and newest. Price filters work just fine but the newest filter which is constructed just as the other ones, doesn't work. When clicking newest, there's no change in the products. I've console.logged `sort` and it shows the array. Here's my code:

```
    console.log(sort)
    if (sort === "newest") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt)
      );
      
    } else if (sort === "descending") {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
      );
    } else {
      setFilteredProducts((prev) =>
        [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price)
      );
    }
  }, [sort]);
```

And code for my options:

```
            <Option value="newest">Newest</Option>
            <Option value="ascending">Price (High)</Option>
            <Option value="descending">Price (Low)</Option>
          </Select>
```

The default value of sort is "newest"

All products have "createdAt" property:

````
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "631608a6fac350ae5644520f"
  },
  "title": "north face",
  "description": "trekking",
  "image": "https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-jacketclothingjacketfashion-men-dress-wear-cloth-coat-jacket-631522326867zvwfe.png",
  "categories": [
    "women",
    "test2"
  ],
  "size": [
    "M",
    "S"
  ],
  "color": [
    "yellow",
    "green"
  ],
  "price": 1,
  "inStock": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1662388390011"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1662388390011"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}```
````

Comment: Do all the products have createdAt property? Can you add the products to the question?

Comment: " I've console.logged sort and it shows the array." Sorry, did you mean you console.logged sort and it shows "newest"? prev is where the array of sortables is stored right?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes all products have createdAt. Added an example product.

Comment: @JonA yes console.log(sort) just before the if statement shows "newest".  This is the prev:  `useEffect(() => {
    category &&
      setFilteredProducts(
        products.filter((item) =>
          Object.entries(filter).every(([key, value]) =>
            item[key].includes(value)
          )
        )
      );
  }, [products, category, filter]); `

Comment: You showed a product collection in mongodb, here we are in reactjs side, do the all product objects in react side also have createdAt?

Comment: @SuleymanSah good point! how can I check that?

Comment: `console.log(products)`

Comment: if the react side also same, you can try b.createdAt.date-a.createdAt.date

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes I can confirm they have createdAt on the client side as well. console.log(products) bring up the array which has that property.

Comment: Did you try `b.createdAt.date-a.createdAt.date`

Comment: @SuleymanSah tried, didn't work.